# Postgres error in batch insert : relation "hibernate_sequence" does not exist position 17

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I am performing hibernate jpa batch update and its giving me following error

```
2015-04-21 15:53:51,907 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (Thread-283 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-462057890)) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01
2015-04-21 15:53:51,908 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (Thread-283 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-462057890)) ERROR: relation "my_seq_gen" does not exist
```

I am using postgres database and my ID is auto generated

```
  @Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="seq-gen",sequenceName="MY_SEQ_GEN"initialValue=205, allocationSize=12)
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="seq-gen")
@Column(name="\"ID\"",unique=true,nullable=false)
private int id;
```

This is my batch insert code snippet

```
getEm().getTransaction().begin();
System.out.println("transaction started--------------");
try {   
    for (Receipt ReceiptEntity : arrReceiptEntity) {
            getEm().persist(ReceiptEntity);
    }
    getEm().getTransaction().commit();
    System.out.println("commited");
} catch (Exception exception) {
    System.out.println("error----------------------------------------------------------------------");
    if(getEm().getTransaction().isActive())
        getEm().getTransaction().rollback();
    LOG.error(exception);
} finally {
    getEm().flush();
    getEm().clear();
    getEm().close();
}
```

I have added the following property in persistence.xml

```
         <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="true"/>
```

Please suggest what i am doing wrong.

Comment: try GenerationType.IDENTITY instead of  GenerationType.AUTO

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25279598/592355

Answer (score 121):

Try to annotate your `id` with `@Id` and `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
```

---

**UPDATE:** It will only work if your id column was declared as `SERIAL` or `BIGSERIAL` types.

Comment: Isn't IDENTITY is bad option for Postgresql?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041938/how-to-choose-the-id-generation-strategy-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate

Comment: @Erlan I see no reason why it should be bad, neither from your link, nor from my experience. Can you explain your point?

Comment: @VsevolodPoletaev. Answers from link mentioned that IDENTITY is useful when there is no option of SEQUENCE because it will disable batch execution. But then found out that in hibernate 5 IDENTITY will bind id to SERIAL's sequence, so it should be ok. Thanks for answer.

Comment: @Mikhail, you are right. It's written in docs http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-generators-identity . But it's not important in most usecases.

Comment: Thanks for the tip and update! Spring Boot does the Rest! ;)

Comment: As far as I am concerned, your answer did the trick for me! I simply added basic identifier properties like not null and unique and all was good!! THUMBS UP

Answer (score 33):

If you don't want to change your entity definition, then you need to create a sequence in your postgreSQL schema with name `hibernate_sequence`.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE hibernate_sequence START 1;
```

**UPDATE**:

You are missing second sequence generatef, which you defined for your entity, just add it like previous one:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE my_seq_gen START 1;
```

What is a sequence?

Sequence is an ordered list of integers. The orders of numbers in the sequence are important. You can configure what is the min and max values, by what amount you should increment it:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE [ IF NOT EXISTS ] sequence_name
  [ AS { SMALLINT | INT | BIGINT } ]
  [ INCREMENT [ BY ] increment ]
  [ MINVALUE minvalue | NO MINVALUE ] 
  [ MAXVALUE maxvalue | NO MAXVALUE ]
  [ START [ WITH ] start ] 
  [ CACHE cache ] 
  [ [ NO ] CYCLE ]
```

No you can use functions like `nextval('')` in your SQL commands and in hibernate to get next value from the set. This is much cheaper than keepipng current primary key value in a sequence_table or looking for max PK value in existing table. So it provides an easy and cheap way to find next PK for given table.

All tables usually use a dedicated Sequance, and like in this example it was chosen as IdGenerator strategy.

Sore useful tutorial:

- http://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/generatedvalue-strategy-generationtype-sequence-hibernate
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-createsequence.html
- https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-sequences/

Comment: I have added sequence generator but its giving another error please check the updated question

Comment: As your exception says, you are still missing one sequence my_seq_gen, add it as previously.

Comment: Worked, like a charm, not sure what actually happens when you create the above sequence, if you could provide an explanation would be cherry on top.

Answer (score 10):

I hope you get the answer but if you are still finding the answer this could be helpful.

I had same problem and resolved it annotating getter method of the id with `@SequenceGenerator` and `@GeneratedValue`.

```
@SequenceGenerator(name="seq-gen",sequenceName="MY_SEQ_GEN", initialValue=205, allocationSize=12)
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="seq-gen")
public int getId(){
    return id;
}
```

Comment: No. It does not solve my problem. Still see `Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')` and this sequence does not exist initially in the schema. Have to create it manually like `CREATE SEQUENCE hibernate_sequence START 1;`, as the former answer.

Answer (score 5):

Check **application.properties** file.

make sure that spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = **update**

Comment: this fixed my initial error same as in the question

Comment: Not recommended for production, preferred approach is to use Flyway with custom DDL scripts.

Answer (score 3):

Can you try following :

```
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "auto_gen")
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "auto_gen", sequenceName = "A")
  @Column(name = "ID")
  private int id;
```

Thanks

Comment: I have added sequence generator but its giving another error please check the updated question

Answer (score 2):

I was with the same problem.I solved  puting auto increment on id column from the table  on postgres it works, like that.

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('mytable_id_seq');

ALTER SEQUENCE mytable_id_seq OWNED BY mytable.id;
```

Answer (score 2):

According to a post, [hibernate could not get next sequence value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628099/hibernate-could-not-get-next-sequence-value/15286642)
 , set your **@GeneratedId** column with strategy **GenerationType.IDENTITY** instead of **GenerationType.SEQUENCE**. So, you would have

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="seq-gen",sequenceName="MY_SEQ_GEN"initialValue=205, allocationSize=12)
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator="seq-gen")
@Column(name="\"ID\"",unique=true,nullable=false)
private int id;
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your application.properties

```
# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

This will explicitly set to create or update all tables during Spring startup.

Answer (score 2):

Recently I had the same issue and I have resolved it by using  `@GenericGenerator` annotation. The issue was because I had to insert hundreds of rows with SQL statements in liquibase changelog and somehow hibernate does not pick up last row and its before generating id.

```
@Entity(name = "domain")
@Table(name = "domain", schema = "public")
public class DomainJpa {

    @Getter
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "incrementDomain")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "incrementDomain", strategy = "increment")
    private Integer id;

}
```

hopefully this can be useful for someone. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case adding property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="**update**", solved the issue. You have to add the mentioned property in persistence.xml

Comment: Worked for me (but I tried with **create**). Watch out: This option deletes all the data from your database and is intended for development only.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes with `@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)` annotation you can have your sequence with **empty intervals** (after delete) and **incorrect next autoincrement position**. Try to **set next autoincrement value** to the position after biggest id value:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE schema.entity_id_seq RESTART WITH 40072;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;
```